# LaTeX Beamer - How to highlight a different author in the footer in each slide?

Tags: latex, beamer

I'm writing a beamer with different authors.

```
\author{Author 1 \\ Author 2 \\ Author 3 \\ Author 4}
```

I have a template footer that looks like this :

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
    leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{author in head/foot}
    \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}%
      \insertshortauthor}
    \hfill
   \insertdate
    \hfill%
    {\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}
```

I'd like to put in bold a certain author in different slides (who talks during the presentation) but I don't know how to change the footer to make something that would help me with a single command at the beginning of the frame make it understand that I'd like a certain author to be highlighted.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the short author between frames:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\author[\textbf{Author 1} Author 2 Author 3 Author 4]{Author 1 \\ Author 2 \\ Author 3 \\ Author 4}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
    leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{author in head/foot}
    \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}%
      \insertshortauthor}
    \hfill
   \insertdate
    \hfill%
    {\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\author[Author 1 \textbf{Author 2} Author 3 Author 4]{}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked amazingly thanks !

Comment: @sam You're welcome!